# Python JSON REST framework with (de)serialiser and schema validation (jsonschema/avro)

Tags: python, json, deserialization, avro, jsonschema

I think my problem is very common. I want to build a JSON REST API in Python (and possibly R later) to exchange data between applications. (I don't want to use BJSON or other binary formats at this point)

Given the availability of schemas and (de-)serialization frameworks, I thought it would be straightforward to build a system that does the following:

1. it takes an input over HTTP get request,

   converts/parses/deserializes it to a python object,

   validates the python object given a common schema language description,

   does something with the parameters to get result data, and

   serialized the result data to JSON,

   validates the result json,

   returns it.

I want to use a schema language that is language-agnostic - nothing that's used only in one language. I looked at avro and json-schema as schema languages and the ecosystem for (de)serialization, but I couldn't find so far any tools that cover the bill. A particular problem is deserialization. There are some libraries that serialize, but then have problems with URL GET parameters that come as strings instead of integers.

?name=Mickey&age=4

given a schema (avro)

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "User",
"namespace": "example.avro",
"fields": [
    {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string"
    },
    {
    "name": "age",
    "type": "int"
    }
]
}
```

I want to get a dict(name='Mickey', age=4).

I've lost a lot of time already trying out different tools and frameworks, and I am at a point, where I am considering writing a deserializer from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking around a lot, not finding what I was looking for. Projects like [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) came close. They allow specification of schemas and provide for serialization, however I wanted the jsonschema format for interoperability.

So I've written my own serializer/deserializer class around a pandas dataframe, which represents the data. It has methods

1. for creating a dataframe from a dictionary or json object (deserialization) 2. for coercing data types,
2. for inferring a schema,
3. for validating the schema, and
4. for serialization to json.

Comment: See here for a framework based on marshmallow https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec

Comment: for information, to the time being, marshmallow project is still actively maintained

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what your problem with serialization and deserialization is. Most web frameworks would not treat URL query parameters as a JSON object, but rather treat each key separately and allow you to access the query string as a dictionary (or as arguments to the request handler, depending on framework). Something like `request.query['name']`. JSON usually appears as the payload for POST, PUT, PATCH and as the response of the request. Even in that case, you get it as a string and do something like `json.loads` to obtain Python data structures, which you're then free to validate with a json-schema or avro validator library.

Comment: If I use json.loads to convert the request parameters, I get dict(name="Mickey", age="4"), both as string, and the validation fails. The schema is available, and I expect the conversion to use it in parsing.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're parsing? You can't use json.loads on a query string such as ?name=Mickey&age=4.

Comment: I thought you suggested json.loads. 

What I am using is the flask requests library. 
    for name in request.args:
       app.logger.debug(name + ": " + str(request.args.get(name, type=int)) + ", type: " + str(type(request.args.get(name, type=int))))

And I see: 
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016 12:45:26] "GET /test?name=Mouse&age=8 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
age: 8, type: <class 'int'>

But it's a string if I don't explicitly ask for type conversion.

Comment: As for post, flask provides request.form: 
        for name in request.form:
            app.logger.debug(name + ": " + str(request.form.get(name, type=int)) + ", type: " + str(type(request.form.get(name))))

output: 
`DEBUG in flask_inputs_example [flask_inputs_example.py:49]:
age: 8, type: <class 'str'>`

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to my mind.

First, there's an [Eve REST framework](http://python-eve.org/), written on top of Flask.

It's author also created (and used in Eve) a schema/validation language, called [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/), which does exactly what you want. Eve stores your JSONs in MongoDB.

If your application is not meant to be very extensive and use various tools that are already available in Django out-of-the-box or as packages, I'd stick with Eve. (oops, did't intend to start the eternal Django-vs-Flask flame here)

---

Second, there's [Mongoengine library](http://mongoengine.org/) that provides Django-style schemas for JSONs.

It was intended to be a support of MongoDB for Django and design of its architecture mimics that of Django. Mongoengine itself is quite stable, but its integration with nice [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), [Django REST Framework-Mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine), is not by any means.

Besides, there are bindings of Mongoengine to Eve and Flask.

Comment: I am familiar with Eve and Mongoengine, and I've looked at cerberus, however there are two issues: 1. they don't support language-agnostic schemas. You are supposed to write your schema in python code? I want to use a schema that later can be picked up in php, R, or other languages. 2. they provide validation, but not schema-based parsing.

Comment: @ben26941 Hm, stumbled upon jsonschema support in python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema. Might be possible to use it in combination with Flask and PyMongo, I guess? And JSON Schema/Angular-JSON-Schema + tv4 on frontend.

Comment: jsonschema, the library, only does validation, but not parsing. What's the point in a library telling you, the dict you got from a json string doesn't conform, without helping you to correct it?